# PowerBI filtering rows from table visual when values are missing

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables in a data model linked with a many-to-one relationship, cross filtered in both directions.

Table A has one row per value of the key, table B has many.

Not everybody from Table A appears in Table B.

I want to create a table visual which lists everybody in Table A, together with information from Table B, if present. However, when I add a variable from Table B to the visual, rather than displaying an empty cell for missing values, PowerBI automatically removes everybody from Table A who doesn't appear in Table B.

What I've got in the data model:

Table A

| Name | Birthday |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2-Apr-1962 |
| Jane | 3-Nov-1970 |

Table B

| Name | Pet |
| --- | --- |
| John | Cat - Henry |
| John | Dog - Spot |

The visual I want:

| Name | Birthday | Pet |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2-Apr-1962 | Cat - Henry |
| John | 2-Apr-1962 | Dog - Spot |
| Jane | 3-Nov-1970 |  |

What I'm getting:

| Name | Birthday | Pet |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2-Apr-1962 | Cat - Henry |
| John | 2-Apr-1962 | Dog - Spot |

There are no filters on my visual.

If I filter the visual to blank / missing values of the variable from Table B, I get an empty table.

I've looked at a few threads here on combining tables with missing data, but they're all about creating new tables in a data model rather than a visual.

Comment: This is a question with a nice, minimal reproducible example, well done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default PowerPivot does **INNER** joins. But if you need **OUTER** joins there is an easy solution (However, don't use bidirectional filtering, if it's not needed): On the table field list go to `Pet`, mouse right-click, select `Show items with no data`:

[image]

And this is what you get:

[image]

It's also straight forward to LeftOuter Join the 2 tables in PowerQuery:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(
        #"Table A", {"Name"}, 
        #"Table B", {"Name"}, 
        "Table B", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Table B" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
        Source, "Table B", {"Pet"}, {"Pet"})
in
    #"Expanded Table B"
```